# What sounds more natural in this case: as, since, or for?

Tags: word-choice

> I couldn't see the rest, **for** I was pushed to the ground.
>
> I couldn't see the rest, **as** I was pushed to the ground.

I assumed both options are correct? In that case, which one sounds more natural? Which is more likely to be said by a native speaker of English?

Comment: **1.** Today, *for* is considered overly literary, avoid it in general English writing. **2.** Note that *as* could mean 'because,' as well as 'at the same time,' though there could be hardly any ambiguity in this particular context. **3.** *Since* is formal; *because* is an excellent fit for all situations. I would, of course, utter/ write the sentence **without** any of them at all -- the pause in speech or the comma in writing eminently serves my purpose. "I couldn't see the rest, I was pushed to the ground."

Comment: *for* is used by Christian evangelists to sound more biblical, to try to associate their statements to the confused/inadequate English/Latin translation of the Hebrew *כי* and *למען*. The usage of which had morphed into early christianized English literature.

Comment: @BlessedGeek Citing a source or giving an opinion? Interesting observation, but the digression could (should) have avoided unrelated analysis.

Comment: "avoided unrelated analysis"? "unrelated" ?

Comment: I didn't know how "to sound more biblical;" ... "christianized English" (or was that "christianized literature"?) could be relevant.

Comment: English usage in England and associated territories after the start of christianization of England and the British Isles. Is there need to explain the contraction of a mouthful of words, in a comment line that hardly gives you any facility to even have a new line?

Comment: If thou hadst the opportunity to associate thyself intimately with the evangelical and fundamentalist movements, thou wouldst encounter the phrase "*sound more biblical*" more than thou wouldst like to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct, yes; but they are also a bit literary, and I don't often hear either one in ordinary conversation. (Rather, I usually hear *because* or *since*.)

But if I had to choose, I'd say that the *as* version is less literary than the *for* version, and more likely to be spoken.

Comment: I come from a family who uses *as* in this way in normal conversation.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct and both occur.  Any potential ambiguity as to whether *as* is here being used in the sense of *while* or in the sense of *because* is done away with in actual speech due to intonation patterns.

It is probably more common to simply say *because* in casual conversation than it is to use either of your two versions.  Other choices include *given that* and *seeing as how*.

Comment: If the OP meant "native, natural," then *because* seems the only way, but it's not one of the options in the Q.  The Q compares *as* with *for.*

Comment: @Kris My family uses *as* here in this sense in ordinary conversation; they never use *for*.  I know other families that never use *as* here.

Comment: But that's not what the answer above says.

Comment: @Kris When did I say I was common? :)